# how to use the phrase 'ups and downs'?

Tags: phrases

I want to ask whether my sentence is correct. I've learned this phrase but I have some problems making a sentence myself. Does it sound natural? " A life having no ups and downs is a dull and unvaried life".
Thank in advance

Comment: Why do you think this usage is correct or incorrect? What research have you done that makes you question yourself?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is grammatical but "having" as a participial modifier is stylistically a bit formal; it would be more natural to say "a life **with** no ups and downs" or "a life **without** ups and downs".

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Hope you have a nice day!